Direct sum of orthogonal complements
Prove that if $$U \oplus W = V,$$ then $$U^ \perp \oplus W^ \perp = V,$$ where $U^ \perp$ is an orthogonal complement of $U$.
I've tried to use the fact that $$U \oplus U^ \perp = V, \ W \oplus W^ \perp = V.$$ Let $dim(V)=m, dim(U)=k \leq m$, then $dim(W)=m-k$ and $dim(U^\perp)=m-k.$ Similarly, $dim(W^\perp)=k.$ Since $dim(U^\perp)+dim(W^\perp)=dim(V),$ then $U^\perp \oplus W^\perp=V.$ However, I'm not sure if I need to prove whether the intersection of $U^\perp$ and $W^\perp$ equals to zero vector. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Yes, you need to prove that $U^\perp\cap W^\perp$ is trivial.
Let $v\in U^\perp\cap W^\perp$. Then $u\cdot v=0$ and $w\cdot v=0$ for each $u\in U, w\in W$. In particular $(u+w)\cdot v=0$ for every $u+w\in U+W=V$ and hence $v\in V^\perp={0}$.

Can you also conclude the result observing that $U\oplus W = U \oplus U^{\perp}$ and therefore $W=U^{\perp}$ and similarly for $U=W^{\perp}$?

Do these spaces $W$ и $U^\perp$ necessarily coincide?

@rcescon that's only true if $\oplus$ denotes an orthogonal direct sum, as opposed to just a direct sum
